# Adding custom field to post object from custom table

Tags: custom-field

I am writing a counter plugin for WordPress, which will keep track of daily and total views.

Normally you would use post meta fields for storing such information. But I cannot:

I cannot use meta fields, because meta fields cannot be updated without the risk of loosing previous values (no locking). For example:

The meta field "dviews" has the value of 10. Request #1 comes in, it will fetch the field and call update_meta with $oldValue + 1 (=11).
This will work in a world where only one request can occur. But in real world, there are multiple concurrent requests. So when the worker from Request #1 is saving "11 dviews", other requests could have already increased the value to 17. Result: The worker from request #1 will set the stats back to 11 - I would loose 7 views. On a quiet busy site, this can be a real problem.

Solution:
I created another table "*views*" with two fields: post_id and dviews.

I can now run an "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATED KEY UPDATE ...*" statement. This is very powerful and I save a query.

Problem:
I now want to show the views in the admin dashboard (as column in the edit.php). I could join my table *views* via hooks like *pre_get_posts*, *posts_fields* and *posts_joins*, so my fields are available in the loop.

But when I want to get a post object (I am using *get_post*), my fields are missing, because the function doesn't use the posts from the loop.

What can I do?

- Write my own "get_post" function?
- Is there another "get_post" function I could use?
- Is it safe to rely on the global $post variable which will show up?
- Adding my columns to WordPress' posts table?

I want to avoid additional queries just for the stats. When displaying 100 postings in a dashboard table, I would get additional 100 queries just for the stats. Not good.
Is there a reliable way to access the already populated posts from the loop? I really don't understand why "get_post" doesn't use this data. Maybe someone can explain?

I also want to avoid manipulating the core tables. But I am not sure if there is a better way, because

```
function &get_post(&$post, $output = OBJECT, $filter = 'raw') {

    // [...]

        if ( ! $_post = wp_cache_get($post_id, 'posts') ) {
            $_post = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID = %d LIMIT 1", $post_id));

    // [...]
}
// (from wp-includes\post.php)
```

will ask a cache and run its own non-hookable query at least.

Comment: Please use the WYSIWG editor buttons to format code. This is a pain to read.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, instead of updating your metafield, add a new one!

Then the problem becomes, which meta has the highest value, and how do I cleanup the other meta fields.

## How I Would Do It

Instead of reinventing the wheel, I can see that Google has already done a brilliant job of counting how many people viewed a page. I can also see Google Analyticator even shows me the top 5 and gives me a chart.

So instead, use the Google APIs, or integrate some other existing solution. Even wordpress.com & WP Stats sends the results off to a remote machine rather than hosting the entire stats package and database locally.

Using post meta, or options, or a custom table etc etc is going to slow down your page loads, make your databases size much larger, and introduce many problems, not just locking table rows.

## A Final Note On Performance

I would also recognise that there is an inherent trade off here, between speed/scalability, and how fresh your data is. If you have a counter on the frontend that's 100% accurate all the time, there are computational and logistical costs associated with it.

An approximate value on the other hand doesn't need to be updated as often and can be cached more easily. Suddenly your program has breathing room and you can adjust the update rate to scale with your site and environment.

Comment: @ Tom J Nowell: I don't understand how multiple metafields should help me. Example: There is already one field with the value 10. Request A would now add a second field with the value 11. But what will the concurrent requests C and D do? They will possible start from an outdated value...

Comment: You are right. I would use Google Analytics, if I would count simple visits. But in this case, "visits" are just an example. I am counting data GA cannot count. So using GA is no option.

Comment: Using multiple tables via simple joins won't affect the performance. So this is not the problem.

And to your final note: There is no different in talking to your cache or running a very simple SELECT statement (if you are already connect to your database).
This would be more a problem, if it would be an additional query, but thanks to the join; it isn't.

Comment: It helps you because the locking problem is no longer relevant. Instead take the meta with the highest value and increment it then save, cleanup some old at regular intervals

Comment: I'm not talking about a select, I'm talking about the UPDATE/INSERT that modifying the database on every single visit would involve. Using multiple meta fields would at least mean using an INSERT rather than an UPDATE which would at least be faster. Also by focusing on accuracy and instant updates, you're paying the price in page speed, as you're unable to spread the cost out over time.

Comment: Also what is this data you speak of that GA cannot count? I'm unaware of data that GA is incapable of tracking, if you can put a tracking code on a page it can be tracked..

Comment: Huh? UPDATEs are faster than INSERTs? Not really... can you show me some kind of proof?

In an non-WordPress web application, I already have counters like I am currently implementing in WordPress. It is a high traffic site and I don't see any problems. Thanks to the DELAYED option.

Counting with GA usually require interaction of the browser (e.g. JS execution). But I am counting internal data, without any JS/Output (data access).

Comment: I said inserts faster than updates, not the other way around.  Also it appears you have neglected to mention vital details in your question. Your question claims your tracking page views yet here you admit you're tracking other things and that you are doing a more generic counter. Also I cannot see your SQL so how am I supposed to know about that?

Comment: Thank you for your time and your commitment.

Unfortunatly I think I have shared all the needed information. The counter is something like a view counter (e.g. most time a posting is viewed, I also increment the counter, but there are exceptions). You said "Use Google Analytics" and I am saying I cannot use GA for that. It would be nice if you would have provided another idea after you got my answer "I cannot use GA" instead of trying to "convince" me to use GA.

Comment: I also mentioned my query in my question. Not complete, but all the important questions are answered, for example if I am using "ON DUPLICATED KEY", there must be a UNIQUE INDEX. In postmeta, there is no UNIQUE INDEX I could use...

I also don't understand why you are saying UPDATEs are slower than INSERTs. If you could explain/show me details, I would appreciate it. But anyway, again thank you for your time. Please don't get me wrong. I don't want to offend you. I appreciate your comments at all.

Comment: I simply asked why you couldn't use Google Analytics, the answer of that question changed the nature of the original question you asked, since you talked about logging pageviews, you didn't mention generic counters.

Comment: As for UPDATE vs INSERT, this is commonly accepted and widely known, an insert just needs to add another row, an update needs to find an existing row, lock it ( or lock its table ), modify the row, save the result, then unlock it. Go look at modern DB systems, they add data, they dont modify data, which has the benefit of giving an instant audit log

Answer (score 1):

MySQL will prevent collisions for you on records that are being written/edited. So you actually CAN use post meta fields to store counters, etc. Just write your own query that reads the value and updates it all at the same time.

Example:

```
update wp_postmeta set meta_value = ( (CAST meta_value AS DECIMAL) + 1 ) where meta_key = "my_counter" and post_id = 123
```

Something like that...

Comment: Am I missing something? I cannot run an "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATED KEY UPDATE ..." query against postmeta table. Making sure there is already a row I can update would be an additional query... am I wrong?

Comment: no, his SQL statement grabs, increments, and updates the post meta all in one action. Also what is this INSERT you speak of? I see an UPDATE statement, not an INSERT.

Comment: ...and that's the problem: To be able to "grab", there must be already something. With my statement (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) I would do an INSERT, but when I already have data, MYSQL would just update the existing row.

Answer (score 0):

First, select and join your custom table:

```php
add_filter('post_clauses', function($clauses) {
    $clauses['fields'] .= ", my_table.my_column";
    $clauses['join'] .= " JOIN my_table ON my_table.post_id = wp_posts.ID";
    return $clauses;
});
```

Then, in the loop you can access the field with `get_post_field('my_column')`